# Fancybox troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to implement a fancybox. http://fancybox.net/howto

I want to call this function on an an element. Full JS file. http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js

```
$.fn.fancybox = function(settings) {
```

I have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a#inline").fn.fancybox();  
});
```

However, I keep getting this error (through firebug):

```
$("a#inline").fn is undefined
[Break on this error] $("a#inline").fn.fancybox();
```

What does this mean? I am basically having instantiating problems.

Please help.

### EDIT

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Technologies</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancy/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancy/fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a#inline").fancybox();  
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include_once ("header.php");
?>
<div id="channel_calc">
How many Channels do I need?
<span id="yellow"><a id="inline" href="#ddm">Channel Calculator</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not what's wrong (unless you have invalid markup, which there's no reason to think you do), but there is no point whatsoever in the `a` part of your `a#inline` selector. The `#` operator in CSS selectors indicates an ID, and IDs are completely unique. No need to qualify that it's the element with ID 'inline' that's also an anchor.

Comment: T.J - I am not an expert on JS/HTML but the guys that created this plugin used this in their example, so I copied it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#inline').fancybox();
```

.fn refers to the prototype.

Comment: I get this: $("#inline").fancybox is not a function
[Break on this error] $("#inline").fancybox();

Comment: Check firebug net tab and see what's missing.

Comment: I've got console and script tabs open. If this is what you mean?

Comment: Make your web page as minimalistic as possible, try mimicking what I have. Post a public url if you could.

Comment: I'm developing on my localhost and i have a very minimalist page. I have pasted relevant HTML.

Comment: Update your <script> src to the absolute URI:

http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js

If it works then it's an issue with how you saved it. How is your site setup locally? Virtualhost? Maybe you need to do src="/fancy/foo.js"

Comment: Also please verify that you actually have the files inside of the 'fancy' directory. 

Somewhere along the lines you just made a simple mistake, be thorough.

Comment: I have verified this, I have even downloaded the files again. Does it matter if I am using relative files?

Comment: Did you try absolutely linking them?

Comment: Yes, I even copied the URL you are using and I still get the same damn errors. Seriously what could possible be causing this. I am happy to listen to remote ideas! If I had some idea of what was going on I would of at least had a chance.

Comment: Before anyone says it, I have been clearing caches after every test.

Comment: OK PROBLEM SOLVED - I should of looked in my header file, I was requiring JQuery there too!! Sorry everyone. :(

Comment: That's what I meant by making it more minimalistic, only the bare necessities.. which would be 3 script elements and html.

Answer (score 2):

Di you find the error? Had the same problem. Solution was that i had included twice a javascript file, rather i included the jquery.js file twice.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem and found that I had included jquery.js twice. Removing the second reference fixed the error I was getting from the fancybox call

Answer (score 1):

$("a#inline").fn.fancybox();  should be $("a#inline").fancybox();

Comment: I have tried this also and I get an error that says fancybox is not a function?! I have used many JQuery plugins before and they were straightforward. I have no idea whats going in here. Probably something simple and stupid.

Comment: Check your path to your fancybox script and make sure it is included before you make a call to the fancybox function.

Comment: Yep, I checked this too. I don't know what else I can do to debug this or solve this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your paths are wrong. Do a view source and copy/paste the paths into your browser. Also make sure that jQuery is included before the fancybox script.

Comment: I also did that and the script appeared fine. Also I am looking at the scripts via firebug. This is getting strange!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure to load fancybox AFTER jquery, otherwise you will get a "fancybox is not a function" error and your other javascript will break as well:

BROKEN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
```

GOOD:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have copied a fragment of your HTML and JS inside jsfiddle.

- When I downgraded to ***jquery 1.3.2***, [see left sidebar under framework in **JSFiddle** example] your code won't work.
- When I upgrade to 1.4.4 or later versions, it worked.

**Solution**

- Try upgrading your jquery to **1.4.4** or later versions and test again.
- Also I noticed you are including an external **header.php**, so make sure there are no other jquery scripts being included in this file or your js codes will break.

See this link for the working example of your own code using **jquery version 1.4.4**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca6N5/

Comment: As per OPs' comment on his accepted answer, his problem was that he was including jQuery twice.  And there is no point in answering a question that was solved nearly three years ago.

Comment: Sorry, I realized the date after having the solution posted. Btw, some solutions may be an "upgrade" to previous answers, since most solutions here were already extinct in nature. But thanks for pointing about the date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to also include jquery itself. Fancybox depends on jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-file/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have included it and I can access it bia my browser.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben said, make sure jQuery is not being included twice by accident.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a#inline").fn.fancybox();
```

1. use newest jquery & fancybox
2. $("a#inline").fancybox();  -> this is correct
3. Here is examples: http://softm.org.ua/google-map-jquery-plugins/